# Stop Mathematica from rounding the value

Tags: random, summation

My task is simple.

> Calculate the average value for 10^7 dice throws using computer pseudo-random-number-generator.

```
x := RandomInteger[{1, 6}]
```

gives me one random value.

```
xn[n_] := 1/n Sum[x, {j, 1, n}]
```

gives me the average value for n throws.

If I set `n = 10^6` its just fine and I get a number around 3.5,
but as soon as I set `n = 10^7`, I get an integer between 1 and 6 with a dot after it, which means that Mathematica rounds the result, right?. The problem is, that Mathematica doesnt even start calculating those 10^7 values.

Of course, I could just sum 10 times `xn[10^6]` and divide it by 10, but I want it to work with `n = 10^7` right away.

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: When trying ${10}^{7}$ values, was it actually returning integers like `1`?  Curious mostly because getting an average of $1$, or even something that rounds to $1$, after ${10}^{7}$ dice throws is absurdly unlikely, so it'd be weird if Mathematica's logic allowed for that result to be returned, even under some sort of approximation logic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Sum` is, at its core, a symbolic method intended to deduce sums of large, perhaps infinite series. To actually add up numbers, use `Total`.

```
xn[n_] := 1/n Total[Table[x, {j, 1, n}]]
xn[10^8]
349988177/100000000
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked.

Comment: a faster solution in the same spirit would be `xn[n_] := ConstantArray[1, n].RandomInteger[{1, 6}, n]/n`

Comment: Why not use `Mean[]`?

Comment: @J. M. For toy problems like this, I try to focus on solving the key issue with minimal change. In this case, the key was replacing `Sum` with something guaranteed to add up numbers rather than trying some more analytic method. Further optimization might be a distraction. But yes, `RandomInteger` can create the whole list in one go, and `Mean` avoids a division.

Answer (score 9):

There is a system option:

```
SystemOptions["SymbolicSumThreshold"]
(*  {"SymbolicSumThreshold" -> 1000000}  *)
```

Above a sum of length 10^6, `Sum` will try a symbolic method.  I'm not sure it's worth trying to explain why a symbolic method will fail on a random summand.

Some alternatives:

```
xn[n_] := With[{opts = SystemOptions["SymbolicSumThreshold"]},
   Internal`WithLocalSettings[
    SetSystemOptions[{"SymbolicSumThreshold" -> n}],
    1/n Sum[x, {j, 1, n}],
    SetSystemOptions[opts]
    ]
   ];

xn[n_] := 1/n Sum[x, {j, 1, n}, Method -> "Procedural"];

xn[n_] := 1/n Total@RandomInteger[{1, 6}, n];   (* bypasses  x  *)
```

The last one will be fastest, probably the fastest possible.

Comment: Actually, I have a guess about the random summand: It appears as `x`, `Sum` assumes it's a constant, and `n*x` is returned.  Somewhere in the process, `x` is evaluated and a random integer between `1` and `6` is the result.

Comment: No need to guess: `Count[#, _RandomInteger, Infinity] & /@ {xn[10^6] // Trace, xn[10^6 + 1] // Trace, xn[10^7] // Trace}`
You are right, for the symbolic evaluation `x` is evaluated only once.

Answer (score 6):

A better way to define `xn` is

```
xn[n_Integer /; Positive[n]] := Mean[RandomInteger[6, n]]
```

This definition requires `n` to be a positive integer, which is a reasonable constraint for this problem.

Let's look at some evaluations. I use[`SeedRandom`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeedRandom.html) to get reproducible results.

```
SeedRandom[42]; Table[xn[i], {i, 0, 5}]
```

> `{xn[0], 3, 5/2, 4/3, 9/4, 13/5}`

Note that zero is not accepted and that the results are all exact numbers.

Now lets look at `n = 10^7`.

```
SeedRandom[42]; x10to7 = xn[10^7]
```

> `5999573/2000000`

```
x10to7 // N  // InputForm
```

> `2.9997865`

In this case, the machine value contains an accurate representation of the exact number.

```
2.9997865`100 - x10to7
```

> `0.*10^-100`

Answer (score 1):

`RandomInteger[{1, 6}]` is not a 'pure' function. Surely what is happening here is that you're confusing its *symbolic* calculations.

I presume the following is what's happening:

- When you sum $10^6$ terms, the implementation says "Oh, I can just compute all the terms and add them up" rather than doing any symbolic manipulation of the summation, and thus evaluates the `RandomInteger` function for every term.
- When you sum $10^7$ terms, the implementation says "Oh, that's a lot; I'll do symbolic manipulation". It sees that the formula being summed does not involve `j` or `n` in any fashion, and infers it to be a *constant*, and thus `Sum[x, {j, 1, n}]` gets simplified to `x n`, and thus evaluates `RandomInteger` only once.

Answer (score 0):

I just got it working, by using the numerical value for every summand:
xn[n_] := Sum[N[x/n], {j, 1, n}]

Still I would like to know, why my first solution didnt work at high numbers, but at lower ones...